# Vuetify v-data-table pop selected row

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to pop selected row in v-data-table so that I can highlight select row. Actually I am doing edit functionality within v-data-table as shown in the picture [image]. Can anybody here to help me regarding this. Most probably it's CSS related. I am proficient in VueJs but not much in CSS

Comment: not idea properly

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify has a v-data-table with selection, target the vuetify css selector to assign a background color of your choice. Or don't target the selected line and add background-color if selection box on left is enough visualization.

```css
.theme--light.v-data-table tbody tr.v-data-table__selected {
    background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <template>
          <v-data-table
            v-model="selected"
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            :single-select="singleSelect"
            item-key="name"
            show-select
            class="elevation-1"
          >
            <template v-slot:top>
              <v-switch
                v-model="singleSelect"
                label="Single select"
                class="pa-3"
              ></v-switch>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </template>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data () {
      return {
        singleSelect: false,
        selected: [],
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```